# Clojure - Convert File Path to Tree

Tags: clojure, tree

I am fairly new to Clojure and I am struggling with how I can use a file path to create a tree in Clojure. I get all the files under a directory using file-seq and store them in `files`. The input is a file path like so:

```
resources/data/2012/05/02/low.xml
resources/data/2012/05/01/low.xml
```

I can get all the individual names of the folders and files using this:

```
(for [x files] 
 (if (.contains (.getPath x) ".json")
  (for [y (str/split (.getPath x) #"\\")] y)))
```

This gives me lists of all the folders but then I don't know how I can combine them into 1 list to create a tree structure. If any answer could explain how their code works as well, to assist with learning. The desired output for these 2 inputs would be:

```
(resources (data (2012 (05 (02 (low.xml)) (01 (low.xml))))))
```

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: I'll add it to the question, helpfully it will gain traction

Answer (score 7, accepted):

what you would need to build trees is something like this:

```
(defn as-tree [data]
  (map (fn [[k vs]] (cons k (as-tree (keep next vs))))
       (group-by first data)))
```

given a list of parsed paths (or in general any sequences), it would create your structure:

```
user> (as-tree [["resources" "data" "2012" "05" "02" "low.xml"]
                ["resources" "data" "2012" "05" "01" "aaa.xml"]
                ["resources" "data" "2012" "05" "02" "high.xml"]
                ["resources" "data" "2012" "05" "01" "xsxs.xml"]
                ["resources" "data" "2012" "06" "01" "bbb.xml"]
                ["resources" "data" "2012" "05" "01" "ccc.xml"]
                ["resources" "data" "2012" "02" "some.xml"]
                ["resources" "data" "2012" "01" "some2.xml"]
                ["other-resources" "data" "2015" "10" "some100.xml"]])

;; (("resources" 
;;   ("data" 
;;     ("2012" 
;;       ("05" 
;;         ("02" ("low.xml") 
;;               ("high.xml")) 
;;         ("01" ("aaa.xml") 
;;               ("xsxs.xml") 
;;               ("ccc.xml"))) 
;;       ("06" 
;;         ("01" ("bbb.xml"))) 
;;       ("02" ("some.xml")) 
;;       ("01" ("some2.xml"))))) 
;;  ("other-resources" ("data" ("2015" ("10" ("some100.xml"))))))
```

so in your case it could look like this (tree for `.clj` files in project):

```
(require '[clojure.string :as cs])
(import 'java.io.File)

(->> (File. ".")
     file-seq
     (map #(.getPath %))
     (filter #(cs/ends-with? % ".clj"))
     (map #(cs/split % (re-pattern File/separator)))
     as-tree
     first)

;;=> ("." 
;;     ("src" 
;;       ("playground" 
;;         ("core.clj"))) 
;;     ("test" 
;;       ("playground" 
;;         ("core_test.clj"))) 
;;     ("project.clj"))
```

Answer (score 2):

With the given file/directory structure:

```
/tmp/root
├── file1.txt
├── file2.txt
├── sub
│   ├── file5.txt
│   └── file6.txt
└── sub1
    ├── emptysub
    ├── file3.txt
    ├── file4.txt
    └── subsub
        └── file99.txt
```

Here's a way to build up (from an empty tree) with a zipper, given those paths:

```
(def paths
  (for [x (file-seq (io/file "/tmp/root"))]
    (keep not-empty (str/split (.getPath x) #"/"))))

(defn level-loc [loc v] ;; find node with value at same depth as loc
  (loop [l loc]
    (when l
      (let [n (z/node l)]
        (cond
          (= n v) l
          (and (coll? n) (= (first n) v)) (-> l z/down)
          :else (recur (-> l z/right)))))))

(defn graft-path [loc path]
  (reduce
    (fn [[_ path :as loc] p]
      (or (level-loc loc p) ;; find existing node
          (if (nil? path)
            ;; appends at top of tree
            (-> loc
                (z/append-child p)
                z/down)
            ;; inserts at depth
            (-> loc
                (z/insert-right (list p))
                z/right
                z/down))))
    loc
    path))

(defn paths->tree [paths]
  (z/root
    (reduce
      (comp z/seq-zip z/root graft-path)
      (z/seq-zip '())
      paths)))
```

Produces the following output:

```
(paths->tree paths)
=>
("tmp"
 ("root"
  ("sub" ("file6.txt") ("file5.txt"))
  ("sub1" ("emptysub") ("subsub" ("file99.txt")) ("file4.txt") ("file3.txt"))
  ("file1.txt")
  ("file2.txt")))
```

Comment: I should note this answer is more about solving the problem _with zippers_ than solving the problem simply/clearly/concisely.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to walk the directory in order as described here:   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html

Another way is to accumulate the result after splitting the pathname into its component strings, then repeatedly using `assoc-in`:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require [clojure.string :as str] ))

(defn accum-tree
  "Accumulates a file path into a map tree"
  [file-elem-tree path-str]
  (let [path-elems (str/split path-str #"/")
        key-seq    (butlast path-elems)
        file-name  (last path-elems)]
    (assoc-in file-elem-tree key-seq file-name)))
```

each call to `accum-tree` works like so:

```
path-elems  => ["resources" "data" "2012" "05" "02" "low.xml"]
key-seq     => ("resources" "data" "2012" "05" "02")
file-name   =>  "low.xml"
```

where the unit test shows the final result.

```
(dotest
  (let [file-strings ["resources/data/2012/05/02/low.xml"
                      "resources/data/2012/05/01/low.xml"]]
    (is= (reduce accum-tree {} file-strings)
      {"resources"
       {"data"
        {"2012"
         {"05"
          {"02" "low.xml",
           "01" "low.xml"}}}}})))
```